# Curly braces in awk reg exp

Tags: regex, awk

I am trying to match a fixed number of digits using curly braces in `awk`but I get no result.

```
# This outputs nothing
echo "123" | awk '/^[0-9]{3}$/ {print $1;}' 

# This outputs 123
echo "123" | awk '/^[0-9]+$/ {print $1;}'
```

Do I need to do something specific to use curly braces?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mac OS X `awk` (BSD `awk`) works with the first command shown:

```
$ echo "123" | /usr/bin/awk '/^[0-9]{3}$/ {print $1;}' 
123
$
```

GNU `awk` does not.  Adding backslashes doesn't help GNU `awk`.  Using option `--re-interval` does, and so does using `--posix`.

```
$ echo "123" | /usr/gnu/bin/awk --re-interval '/^[0-9]{3}$/ {print $1;}' 
123
$ echo "123" | /usr/gnu/bin/awk --posix '/^[0-9]{3}$/ {print $1;}' 
123
$
```

(I'm not sure where `mawk` 1.3.3 dated 1996 comes from, but it is probably time to get an updated version of `awk` for your machine.)

Comment: Thanks, it does not work on my version where I get a `awk: not an option: --re-interval` error (`awk -W version` returns `mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996`) it seems like the general answer.

Comment: Wow: that's an old, old version of `awk`.  Maybe it is time to investigate an upgrade from that version.

Comment: When --re-interval is not an option, that's not gawk. When you need --re-interval, that's an old version of gawk. Either way get the latest gawk.

Comment: It came with Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS, not sure why they don't include a newer version.

Comment: mawk is a minimal functionality awk, optimized for speed of execution, so whether it's old or new you should get a different awk.

Comment: I was using `gawk` 3.1.7 (from 2009). I'm trying to build `gawk` 4.0.2 but I'm getting stuck with libraries/libtool not working as expected.  I'll continue working on the upgrade...

Answer (score 0):

AWK on **Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS** is up-to-date, released in year **2020** of but its `mawk`.

As [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) stated in a comment above, *"mawk is a minimal functionality awk, optimized for speed of execution,..."*.

Seems those optimizations were at the expense of functionality.

**SOLUTION**
Install GNU awk (gawk):

```
$ sudo apt install gawk -y

$ awk -W version
GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2019 Free Software Foundation.
```